# using jquery to convert php results and showing in input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

couldn't find the right title for this question. but basically I am trying to show a message to a using in an `input`. I don't want to `alert` the result. I have tried

```
if(parseInt(data) == 0) $("#status").text("Not in use").addClass("green"); 

                            else $("#status").text("Already used").addClass("red");
```

and got nothing as a result. I know the php works because I did a `print_r (validation_result);` and `var_dump(validation_result);` Please look at my codes below.

**PHP**

```
 <?php
    require("config.php");

        $validate_value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : null; 
        $validate_Year =isset($_POST['Year']) ? $_POST['year'] : null; 
        $validate_postcode  = isset($_POST['postcode']) ? $_POST['postcode'] : null; 
        $select = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE reg_year= :reg_year 
                     AND reg_code = :reg_name AND reg_value = :reg_value  LIMIT 1";

                    $bind_bb = array('reg_year' => $validate_Year,
                                        'reg_code' => $validate_code,
                                        'reg_value' => $validate_value);


                    $validate_result = select_to_array($db_connect,$select, $index, $bind_bb);


            if (count($validate_result) == 0) {   

            echo 'Customer Does not no exist';

            }       
            else {

            echo 'Already exist, please try a different postcode';

            }       
    ?>
```

**Jquery** // what I have tried

```
$(function(){
    $('#value').change(function() {
    if (value== "") {

    } else {
     $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'insert_value.php',
                  data:{
                   validate_value:$('#value').val(),
                   validate_year:$('#year').val(),
                   validate_postcode:$('#postcode').val(), 
                  },
                  success: function (data) {

                        if(parseInt(data) == 0) $("#status").text("Not in use").addClass("green"); 

                        else $("#status").text("Already used").addClass("red");

                  }
              })

   }

});
});
```

**HMTL**

```
 <input type="text" name="postcode"  id="postcode"  size="12" maxlength="50" />
  <input type="text" name="year"  id="year"  size="12" maxlength="50" />
   <input type="text" name="value"  id="value"  size="12" maxlength="50" />
    <input /><div id="status"></div>
```

In the `success:function` when I do a `alert(data);` its shows the messages in the function depending if what i am checking in the table already exist. but when i remove the `alert` and replace it with the `if` statement above it doesn't show the message in the `status` input.

what am I doing wrong? and how can I improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using parseInt(data) == 0, when your php returns a string ?

Comment: @RomainBraun how can i improve it?

Comment: the formatting is messed up. you might want to fix this so the PHP code is shown appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code, code is seems fine. Please make sure you have only one `status` id in your elements, it should be  unique.

```
$(function(){
   $('#value').change(function() {
    var value =$(this).val();
   if (value== "") {

   } else {
     $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url:'insert_value.php',
              data:{
               validate_value:$('#value').val(),
               validate_year:$('#year').val(),
               validate_postcode:$('#postcode').val(), 
              },
              success: function (data) {

                    if(parseInt(data) == 0) $("#status").text("Not in use").addClass("green"); 

                    else $("#status").text("Already used").addClass("red");

              }
          })

        }

    });
 });
```

Comment: i got a question. I tried what you said and it always say "Already used" even thought I have enter something that is not in the database. do I need to change anything in the php for this to work? and what will that be?

Comment: You need check insert_value.php is inserted correctly, once it exceuted you return as `0` from insert_value.php.

Comment: the insert_value.php is working correctly. for the return as `0` do you mean `if (count($validate_error_check) == 0) {   
        
                    return '0';
  }  
        else {

        return '1';

  } 
       
                 `

Comment: I did. please check the question again